# Delivering Optimal performance with Typescript and RequireJS

Tags: requirejs, typescript

I have a Typescript project with plenty of circular dependencies. I am using requireJS for loading files on the browser. I am trying to refactor the project and I don't really know how to do it for optimal performance.

Here's the situation.

```
A.ts references B.ts and C.ts
B.ts references A.ts and C.ts
C.ts references A.ts and B.ts
```

1. I can either put reference tags in them and compile them with the --out option in the Typescript compiler into a single file. This make it hard to compile and debug so I am not inclined on this one.
2. I can use RequireJS to load them as independent modules.However, I am concerned because of the fact that there are so many circular dependencies - the browser will make too many requests for the same file. Secondly, I'm wondering if one one file request will cost considerbly lower bandwidth than multiple files of equal to to the sum of their sizes.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to call require again to actually get the instance. See http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#circular

RequireJS never requests the same file twice on the network so you should not worry about that.